# JPA manually load collections

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity holding a collection (`@OneToMany`) which loads lazily. So far so good. If I load the entire list of entity objects (`findAll()`) I don't want the collection loaded at all. I don't access the collection therefore I assumed it will not be loaded before returning it from a REST endpoint, but it seems like Jackson accesses it when parsing it into JSON.

Currently I iterate over the entire entity list and set the collection to `NULL`. This seems like a very poor way of doing it, is there a way to ONLY manually load the collection with a specially prepared `@Query` and not load it automatically (either LAZY no EAGER) at all? Are `@JsonViews` the correct way to go or should I remove the `@OneToMany` annotation (I guess then I lose the mapping for the queries that actually do load the collection)? Any other suggestions?

**Examplecode**

@Entity

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
  @OneToMany(targetEntity = Child.class)
  private List<Child> children;

}
```

Jersey Resource

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Entity> getAllEntities() {
  List<Entity> entities = entityService.findAll();

  entities.forEach(e-> e.setChildren(null));

  return entities ;
}
```

Repository = JpaRepository with default `findAll()` implementation.

thanks

Comment: Well a couple of thoughts - Don't use the same java class to abstract database table and JSON Response Entity. Introduce a new object - EntityResponseDto or whatever and use that in your Resoruce. It's bad to have Jackson "controlling" the behaviour of your Entity class. I think introducing the new class will give you control over what gets passed to the Jackson serializer. No problem to use JsonViews on that new class.

Comment: Is this a best practice? I find it a little bit unnecessary to create special objects for every entity or endpoint if it is very similar or identical to the original.

Comment: Depends on what you want to build and what your focus is. If you want to have independent/reusable layers is good to have those separated. In your case you're giving 1 object 2 responsibilities and you're mixing 2 layers this way - DAO and REST layers. Most of the time this is considered bad practice. Of course if you don't care about layered architecture, your DB model is simple and you want to save time.. well you can do whatever is necessary. What happens if you have complex case where you have to use heavily Jackson and JPA annotations? That will be very cumbersome in the same class.

Comment: I guess you and @yugo are right. Do you have an example to what's best to parse the DTO to the DAO object and the other way around? Using each others constructors seems like another tight coupling. Should I implement special parsers? thanks

Comment: I wouldn't worry very much about that. It's a repeatable/boring blocks of code. You can write your own ObjectMapper if you want. Initially I would introduce a method in each Entity class - smth like - asEntityResponseDto() which will simply set the fields of the Entity class into the Dto class and return it.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the DTO objects (Data Transfer Objects) are used exactly for that - to transfer data between the different layers. So when you say - DAO and DTO seems to you like tight coupling - that's expected and it's OK. The idea is to avoid coupling between DAO/Service/REST layers etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned 'suggestion', I faced the same problem myself and I decided to implement custom DTOs to be sent in the API response. So I ommitted these collection fields and all other I did not want the json processors to touch.
I did implement my set of DTOs mirroring actual persisted entities, but there might be some other mappers to do the job

Comment: That's the way to go!

Comment: BTW I did not even apply dependencies between entities and DTOs.. I created a util class that performs the value-copying between the entity and DTO and vice-versa, in public static  methods.

Answer (score 1):

A few time ago, I asked a question about [designing model classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697038/designing-model-classes-in-jax-rs) for a REST API. There might be some information there useful for you.

Instead of reusing the same model classes for persistence and for the REST API, I've realized the best approach was creating different models. In some situations you don't want the persistence model to be the same as the model you use in your API. So, defining different models is the way to go.

And I chose [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) to map from one model to other.